# Discord.js: Is there a function that can check whether the user has a rank from the array of ranks

Tags: javascript, arrays, discord.js

I'm currently working on a discord bot that has multiple commands that are only for specific roles.
I currently have all roles that are allowed to use the commands in an array and my code below works.

```
        for (var i = 0; i < Config.AllowedRanks.length; i++) {
            if (message.member.roles.cache.has(Config.AllowedRanks[i])){
                console.log("Access Granted")
        }
     }
```

But how do I make it so that everyone else that doesn't have the role, gets a message that the access is denied? The code below does the thing I want but also does it when someone has the role when that role is not first in the array.

```
        for (var i = 0; i < Config.AllowedRanks.length; i++) {
            if (message.member.roles.cache.has(Config.AllowedRanks[i])){
                console.log("Access Granted")
        } else{
                console.log("Access Denied")
        }
     }
```

The answer thanks to Bqre:

```
        if (Config.AllowedRanks.some(role => message.member.roles.cache.get(role))){
            console.log("Access Granted")
        } else{
            console.log("Access Denied")
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this specific case, we would want to use the `.some()` method, that loops through an entire array and checks if at least **one** of the elements matches a certain condition.

For example, let's create an array of role IDs:

```
const roles = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];
```

What we can do from here, is take the array we have created, and check if the author has at least **one** of the roles with one of the IDs above using the `.some()` method.

#### Final Code

```
const roles = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];
if (roles.some(role => message.member.roles.cache.get(role))) console.log('Access Granted.');
else console.log('Access Denied.');
```

Respectively, the same would work for the `.every()` method, that instead checks if all of the elements of an array match the condition - In our case, if the user has all of the roles above.

Comment: The final code had some errors in it but after some tinkering, it finally worked.
See question for correct code.

Comment: Accidentally missed a `)`, woopsie.